# Matplotlib animation: interactive zoom/pan with blitting does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found a strange problem with FuncAnimation in matplotlib when using blitting. The following code is a minimal working example which moves a point along a sinusoidal line. The problem ist, that after an interactive zoom/pan operation the axes a redrawn, but the line plot stays on it's original position on screen. It seems that for some reason, a zoom/pan does not trigger a new initialization of the blitting. I am using the Qt5Agg backend with matplotlib 3.0.2 but the problem ist also present with the TkAgg backend. A possible workaround is to make the function update also return the line plot. However, that somehow foils the idea of blitting. Do you know a better fix for this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

line, = ax.plot(t, y)
point, = ax.plot(0, 0, 'o')


def update(i):
    point.set_data([t[i], y[i]])
    return point,


ani = mpl.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=t.size, blit=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want to blit the line as well, use `return line, point`.

Comment: yes, of course, but the point is that the line is should not be redrawn during each update. The line is static and should not be animated.

Comment: Drawing the line is peanuts against drawing everything, so it's still much faster than not using blitting.

Comment: Yes you are completely right when looking at the given minimal working example. However, the situation is completely different if the static part consists of much more than a single line plot. Consider for example a case, where you have a static quiver plot which visualizes some field and a couple of points moving around. In this case, your solution would almost completely destroy the benefits of blitting.

Comment: It's sure not optimal, but still much faster.

Comment: Whether it is much faster or just a bit faster depends on the amount of static stuff that is drawn. In addition, this solution clutters the code, because you have to track each artist that is added to the corresponding axes just to return it in the update-function. This is of course a possible solution that is still somewhat faster than without blitting, but I think that this solution somehow unsatisfactory.

Comment: Did you do any timings on a actual use case? How different are the frame rates?

Comment: One use case is where a single point is moving in front of a static pcolormesh. A typical result is: ~10 fps without blitting, ~13 fps with your proposal, ~60 fps with the original update function.

This example, is of course, the extreme case, where the entire background has to be redrawn in each frame, and I agree with you that in some use cases, your porposal is a good solution. However, I think, it would be more elegant, if we could force the animation routine to re-initialize the blitting in case of a pan/zoom interaction just as it is done with a figure-resize action.

Comment: Yep you're right, there is no good reason why a resize event should use a new snapshot, but a change of axes limits should not. I can imagine a reason though... limits change events are bound to an axes, so you cannot register them globally to a figure. (`ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', ...)` vs. `fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", ..)`). So one would need to connect all the figure's axes and then manage the simultaneous emission of xlim and ylim. It's probably the kind of problem that if you manage to solve externally, you could directly submit that code as patch to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the help of ImportanceOfBeingErnest I found the following solution:

```
ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', lambda event: ani._blit_cache.clear())
ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', lambda event: ani._blit_cache.clear())
```

I will try to file a patch for FuncAnimation.